# HTML5 Canvas blendmode

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm new to HTML5 canvas and I want to reproduce the result of `BlendMode.ADD` in ActionScript 3.

According to the documentation, here's what `BlendMode.ADD` does:

> Adds the values of the constituent colors of the display object to the
>   colors of its background, applying a ceiling of 0xFF. This setting is
>   commonly used for animating a lightening dissolve between two objects.
>
> For example, if the display object has a pixel with an RGB value of
>   0xAAA633, and the background pixel has an RGB value of 0xDD2200, the
>   resulting RGB value for the displayed pixel is 0xFFC833 (because 0xAA
>   + 0xDD > 0xFF, 0xA6 + 0x22 = 0xC8, and 0x33 + 0x00 = 0x33).

**Source:** http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BlendMode.html#ADD

How can I do the same thing to an image in **HTML5 Canvas**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1/#porterduffcompositingoperators_plus) of the 2D canvas has implemented the blending mode with the name "**lighter**" (not to be confused with *"lighten"* which is a different mode) that will do "add".

```js
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#037";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 130, 130);

ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "lighter";  // AKA add / linear-dodge
ctx.fillStyle = "#777";
ctx.fillRect(90, 20, 130, 130);
```

```html
<canvas id=c></canvas>
```

(update: I was remembering (incorrectly) *lighten* as the name for it, so sorry for the extra manual step in the original version of the answer).